# BehaviorSubject stream unit test, fail actual data

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

can You please help me to understand how to test the BehaviorSubject with my custom class(TestClass).

the test returns `Instance of 'BehaviorSubject<TestClass>'` instead of `Instance of 'TestClass.`

but with primitive types it work fine

Full error:

```
ERROR: Expected: should emit an event that <Instance of 'TestClass'>
  Actual: <Instance of 'BehaviorSubject<TestClass>'>
   Which: emitted • Instance of 'TestClass'
```

bloc example:

```
class TestDataBloc {
  final testSubject = BehaviorSubject<TestClass>();

  Observable<TestClass> get paymentStream => testSubject.stream;

  createOrder() {
    final TestClass _testData = TestClass(
      id: 100,
      data: "xxx",
    );
    testSubject.sink.add(_testData);
  }

  dispose() async {
    await testSubject.drain();
    testSubject.close();
  }
}
```

test:

```
    test('_testData', () async {
      TestDataBloc _testDataBloc = TestDataBloc();

      final TestClass _testData = TestClass(
        id: 100,
        data: "xxx",
      );

      expect(
        _testDataBloc.testSubject.stream,
        emitsInOrder(
          <TestClass>[
            _testData,
          ],
        ),
      );

      _testDataBloc.createOrder();
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have an equality operator defined for `TestClass`